# What is the "positive form" for negated logic statements?

Tags: logic

Keith Devlin's Coursera course "Introduction to Mathematical Thinking" introduces a precise way to write down logical statements, using quantifiers (for all $\forall$, there exists $\exists$) and boolean operators (and $\wedge$, or $\vee$, not $\neg$).

In some exercises he asks us to negate a statement and write it in "**positive form**."

However, I can't find any explanation of what "positive form" is - this is my question.

My guess is as follows:

---

Statement:

$$ (A \implies B) $$

Negation:

$$ \lnot (A \implies B) $$

Positive form of negation:

$$ (A \land \lnot B) $$

I am guessing that "positive form" means doing more than just prepending a statement with "it is not the case that". Is this correct?

Comment: That would be also my guess.

Comment: My guess would be that negation is only applied to variables and not to larger terms.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger So, to be clear, a sentence being in "positive form" means that none of its compound subsentences are being negated (i.e., the only subsentences being negated are atomic ones)?

Comment: @ryang That's my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devlin alludes to the meaning of "positive form" in **Week $3$: Tutorial for Assignment 5** (timestamp $2$:$30$). See link [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking/lecture/ew0c6/tutorial-for-assignment-5).

Specifically, he rewrites the formula $\neg ( \exists x \in \mathbb{N} ) [x^3 = 28]$ as the logically equivalent formula $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N}) \neg [x^3 = 28]$ using [DeMorgan's Law for quantifiers](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section01.03.html), which can be rewritten as $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N}) [x^3 \neq 28]$ by definition of $\neq$.

Although he does not give a precise definition of "positive form," his use of the term suggests that a formula is in positive form whenever it is expressed as a logically equivalent and unnegated formula. So I believe your intuition is correct, that is, the positive form of $\neg (A \to B)$ would be $ A \wedge \neg B$.

Defined in this way, positive form is equivalent to [negation normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form). A formula is in negation normal form whenever $(a)$ the negation operator is only applied to variables, and $(b)$ the only other allowed logical operators are conjunction $\wedge$ and disjunction $\vee$.

Note the positive form of a formula tends to make the formula more comprehensible to the reader.

Comment: I have also seen this called "[negation normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form)" (in a more precise context). It is not just useful for being comprehensible to humans; it is also useful for proofs about the structure of logical expressions, because there are fewer cases to consider.